# How to output Javascript string with character encoding

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

So - I have a string in javascript liks so:

```
var foo = "Hello&trade;";
```

I need to print this out in HTML (via JS) so it looks like this:

Hello™

Sounds easy, but I obviously am missing something cause I can't figure out a simple solution for it yet.

EDIT -  here is more code:

```
var label = document.createElement('label');
var foo = selectData.options[i][1]; // this is "Hello&trade";

label.innerHTML = foo;

container.appendChild( label );
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just append it into the `innerHTML` property. 
`innerHTML` will html encode the given input and that append it to the node.

```js
var foo = "Hello&trade;";

document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = foo;
```

```html
<label id="label"></label>
```

Comment: Don't you think this is a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: Have you checked the example

Comment: That doesn't appear to work.

    var foo = "Hello&Trade;";
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerHTML = foo;

results in the label being "Hello&Trade";

Comment: I posted some more code showing some more context to my issue

Comment: I found the bug, the issue was that I was getting passed &Trade and not &trade -  so the symbol could not convert properly.    The above is the correct answer, I just couldn't see it

Answer (score 0):

First separate the '&trade' and check for it in an if-statement and then give var the value of the hexcode equivalent which is 'u2122' then the rest of the code should do the work.

```
String.prototype.hexEncode = function(){
    var hex, i;
    var result = "";

    for (i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        hex = this.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
        result += ("000"+hex).slice(-4);
        }

    return result
}

    String.prototype.hexDecode = function(){
        var j;
        var hexes = this.match(/.{1,4}/g) || [];
        var back = "";

         for(j = 0; j<hexes.length; j++) {
              back += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hexes[j], 16));
        }

    return back;
}

var str = "\u2122"; 
var newStr = (str.hexEncode().hexDecode());
var foo = "Hello" + newStr;
console.log(foo);
```