# Display html characters in Svelte

Tags: svelte, html-escape-characters

I have a Svelte app [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1a3848da8ae5496e83f7f83f5dcac4f5?version=3.52.0) where I wish to convert strings to html characters.

```
<h1>Test html codes</h1>
{#each lines|| [] as line}
    <div id="comment-line">
        {line}
    </div>
{/each}


<script>
    let rawData = [
        'Abc',
        'Xyz!tm',
        'Mno'
    ]
    $: lines = parseLines(rawData)
    
    function parseLines(array) {
        let new_array = []
        var new_line
        for (var line of array) {
            new_line = line.replaceAll('!tm', '&trade;');
            new_array.push(new_line)
        }
        return new_array
    }
</script>
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48528999/how-to-output-javascript-string-with-character-encoding) suggests that you use *.innerHTML*, but can it be done in a more straightforward way in Svelte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Svelte you can use `{@html line}` which will output *line* as pure html getting the effect you require. Be aware though that is inherently insecure and should only be done with strings you absolutely trust and likely never with user-generated content. (if the string contains a script it will run it for example)

Alternatively consider doing `new_line = line.replaceAll('!tm', '™');` instead.